# Are copy constructor and operator= a must?

Tags: c++, pointers, copy-constructor

I read [somewhere](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs368-2/CppTutorial/NOTES/CLASSES-PTRS.html) that :

> Every class that has a pointer data member should include the following member functions:
>
> 1. a destructor
> 2. a copy constructor,
> 3. operator= (assignment)

Is that really true? What if copying the object makes no sense?

What if the pointer data member in question points to something that doesn't need to be copied, or cannot be changed?

I'll give a concrete example: a person was born in a certain date; Date is an object that holds values like how long the day was or what day of the week it was.
I don't want to "copy" a person, but even if I have to, shouldn't they point to the same Date object?

If it is true, why?

Comment: Your example is not clear. Where is the Date object allocated and deleted? If inside the constructor/destructor, then you have a serious bug since copied Person object's destructor can delete the Date member of the original Person object. If the allocation/dealocation happens outside the class, then that's OK, but it's not typical C++ style.

Comment: Date is allocated before the object exists (I have a data structure with Date pointers), a Person constructor includes a string, and it finds the appropriate Date pointer. People with the same birthday will share the same Date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer data member can mean different things. If the pointer is a mere *observing* pointer (to an object managed elsewhere), then there is absolutely no problem with the compiler generated copy constructor and operator (which simply copy the value of the pointer). A potential problem here is that the pointer may outlive the object, rendering it a *dangling* pointer.

If it is a pointer to memory allocated on the heap and managed by `this`, then you **must** make sure that copy is done appropriately. Simply not implementing copy (constructor and operator) is not an option, since the compiler will automatically create them, and those will most likely not do what you want. Since 2011 (using C++11), you can, of course, `=delete` the copy and/or implement move (constructor and operator) instead.

However, the most sensible thing is to avoid such pointers in favour of data-management classes like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` etc.

Comment: I can't see how std::unique_ptr or std::vector will help here. Perhaps you meant std::shared_ptr

Comment: depends what you're trying to achieve. If the pointer points to memory owned by `this`, then `std::unique_ptr` or `std::vector` are best. `std::shared_ptr` is usually not a good member type for classes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference between the word "should" and the word "must".   When I read the text that you presented, it means to mean that I should strongly consider doing those three things, not that it is an absolute necessity.   Logic, experience, and feasibility will trump guidelines such as those when and where appropriate.

That being said, if it makes sense, it's always good to have those three things in your class.

Answer (score 0):

In your date example, that should not really be a pointer. If it is a pointer, 
and you get a temporary, or a copy, what do the destructor's do? Call 
`delete` on the date-object? If you call `delete` twice (you now have 2 
objects) on the same pointer, its Undefined Behaviour.

Example on what **NOT** to do:

```
class Persson
{
public:
    Persson( string name, string date )
        : m_name(name)
    {
        m_date = new Date;
        ParseDate( *m_date, date );
    }
    ~Persson()
    {
        delete m_date;
    }
private:
    string m_name;
    Date* m_date;
};
```

If you ever make a copy of a `Persson` this will bug out.
It's easy to get a copy, temporary's are everywhere.

A possibility is that the pointers lifetime is managed by someone else, 
in that case the pointer can be seen more as a handle, then it's ok not 
to define copy-constructor, asignment-operator and destructor.

barring an object whose lifetime is managed by someone else, you should 
not really use pointers at all, either use values directly, or smart-pointers.

Less bad example:

```
class Persson
{
public:
    Persson( string name, string date )
        : m_name(name)
    {
        m_date = make_shared<Date>();
        ParseDate( *m_date.get(), date );
    }
private:
    string m_name;
    shared_ptr<Date> m_date;
};
```

Even better Example

```
class Persson
{
public:
    Persson( string name, string date )
        : m_name(name)
    {
        ParseDate( m_date, date );
    }
private:
    string m_name;
    Date m_date;
};
```

Always use value-semantics with C++, its made for that.
Have a look at [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)

Comment: Date stand on it's own. It can be used by different people, it is allocated when the program begins and deleted when it ends.

Comment: that's an example of an object whose lifetime is managed by someone else. you can use a pointer, the default copy-costructor etc will do the right thing. but why design `Date` like that?